# Ajax refresh page URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

Hi everyona i have one question about refreshing page.

I am trying to refresh my chat page. But i have one problem here. I am trying this following code for refresh

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
  });
  setInterval(function() {
      $('#message').load('messageReply.php');
    }, 2000
  );
});
```

So the code is working but url is different.

I used to `.htaccess` for chat page like:

`RewriteRule ^chat/([\w-]+)/?$ /chat.php?chat_username=$1 [L,QSA`]

```
http://localhost:8888/chat/username
```

I am getting this eror from the chrome developer console:

```
GET http://localhost:8888/chat/messageReply.php?_=1436565112775 404 (Not Found)
```

Anyone can tell me how can i fix this error ?

Comment: It's a 404 error. are you sure the url is correct? because that error indicates that it in fact is not correct.

Comment: It sounds like you want an absolute URL.

Comment: @SLaks Yes i want absolute correct URL. You are understand me thanks.

Comment: If your php files is in root folder, you should use /messageReply.php

Answer (score 0):

You're using a relative URL, which the browser resolves from the path to the current page.

You want an absolute URL (starting from the domain root).

Add a `/` to the beginning of the URL.